# What is the preferred abbreviation for "Mathematics Educators"?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What is the preferred abbreviation for "Mathematics Educators"?

Med?

Comment: Completely off topic, but hopefully amusing. My mother's degree is a Bachelors of Music Education. The standard abbreviation is B. Mus. Ed. (say it out loud).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "standard" abbreviation is MESE.  See for example https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and searching for it here on meta one finds it frequently.